# Ordering in geom_dotplot with 2 variables

Tags: r, ggplot2, charts, dplyr

I am using dotplot to do an analysis with two y variables per x variable. I'd like to arrange the chart so that it descends by one of the y variables. I used the reorder() function in the aes() and it reorders it slightly, but not entirely. Chart 1 is what it looks like before, and chart 2 is what it looks like after I use reorder().

Chart 1: [image]

Chart 2: [image]

Here's the code:

```html
answers %>%
    ggplot(aes(x = reorder(locale, -percent) , y = percent, fill = box)) +
    geom_dotplot(binaxis='y', 
               stackdir='center', 
               dotsize = 1,
               binwidth = 0.01) + 
    geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = ci_lo, ymax = ci_hi), width = .5, position = position_dodge(0))
```

And this is what the "answers" df looks like. The two variables being plotted per locale are in the "box" column - there's a top_box and bottom_box row for each locale:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SO. Well done trying to use the code snippet feature, I never used it and it looks fancy. However, - you code does not work if you do not define `answers` and load the required packages previously. Please provide this example data

Comment: you may find `forcats::reorder` useful for this as it manages the order of factor levels in an intuitive way. Make sure do do this before passing the dataframe to ggplot2.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in the comments, you do not provide and data, but I think I have an idea on where you're going wrong.

Here is some example data. I'm going to use a modified `mtcars` for the example where we will look at the min and max weight of the cars by make.

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- mtcars %>% rownames_to_column() %>%
    select(car = rowname, wt) %>% 
    mutate(car = gsub("\\s.*?$", "", car)) %>%
    group_by(car) %>%
    mutate(n = n()) %>%
    filter(n > 1) %>%
    arrange(car,wt) %>%
    filter(row_number() == max(row_number())  | row_number() == min(row_number())) %>%
    select(-n) %>%
    ungroup() %>%
    mutate(stat = rep(c("min", "max"), nrow(.)/2)) %>%
    spread(stat, wt)

print(df)
#  car      max   min
#  Fiat    2.2   1.94
#  Hornet  3.44  3.22
#  Mazda   2.88  2.62
#  Merc    4.07  3.15
#  Toyota  2.46  1.84
```

Here is what the plot for that would look like:

```
df %>%
    ggplot(aes(x = car))+
    geom_point(aes(y = max), color = "red")+
    geom_point(aes(y = min), color = "blue")
```

[image]

Now lets talk about what you're trying to do. You say that you would like to order by descending on one of your variables.

```
df %>%
    arrange(-max)%>%
    mutate(car = factor(car, levels = car))%>%
    ggplot(aes(x = car))+
    geom_point(aes(y = max), color = "red")+
    geom_point(aes(y = min), color = "blue")
```

[image]

or

```
df %>%
    arrange(-min)%>%
    mutate(car = factor(car, levels = car))%>%
    ggplot(aes(x = car))+geom_point(aes(y = max), color = "red")+
    geom_point(aes(y = min), color = "blue")
```

[image]

I think the key here is that you want to `arrange` the data and then set the factor levels to get the desired output. If your data is not a factor, then ggplot will use alphabetical order. You may need to `spread` your data in order to use the exact method outlined above.

**Update**

You could do this without spreading your data, by arranging with two variables.

Here we will modify the data above to long format

```
df2 <- df %>% gather(measure, value, -car)
```

Which plots like this

```
df2 %>% 
    ggplot(aes(x = car, y = value, color = measure))+
    geom_point()
```

[image]

and then we can arrange without spreading

```
df2 %>% 
    arrange(-value, measure) %>%
    mutate(car = factor(car, levels = unique(car)))%>%
    ggplot(aes(x = car, y = value, color = measure))+
    geom_point()
```

[image]

or for descending by min

```
df2 %>% 
    arrange(desc(measure), -value) %>%
    mutate(car = factor(car, levels = unique(car)))%>%
    ggplot(aes(x = car, y = value, color = measure))+
    geom_point()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this! I couldn't figure out how to upload my data which is why I just put the screenshot, but thank you for giving this a go anyway. I think the key was that I need to spread the data out. I effectively had two variables in the same column, and only trying to order on a portion of that column which is where it got confusing. Spreading it out solved the problem and then the arrange(-max) worked. Thank you!

Comment: You could do this without spreading. Hold on, I'll update. I just didn't think about it earlier.